# how to run code when open linked tables file in access

Tags: ms-access

- I have an Access data file that contains tables.
- that access file linked with other access files (the executive file that contains the forms and the operations).

I added the following code inside the tables file inside a module:

```
Public Function MyFun()
On Error Resume Next
Dim xCounter As Integer
xCounter = DLookup("xcounter", "tblfs1", "[xid] = 1")
xCounter = xCounter + 1


    Dim xSql As String
    xSql = "update tblfs1 set [xcounter] = " & xCounter & " where [xid] = 1"
    
    CurrentDb.Execute xSql
If xCounter >= 300 Then
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_FS", acTable, "FS"
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_All", acTable, "All"
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_Customers", acTable, "Customers"
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_Rates", acTable, "Rates"
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_Temp", acTable, "Temp"
    DoCmd.Rename "Tbl_Users", acTable, "Users"
End If
```

End Function

and I created a macro to run that function in a startup (RunCode) and I named the macro (AutoExec).

my problem is when I open (the access tables file) by clicking, the code works but when I use the executive file that linked with (the access tables file), the code doesn't work!!

how to make the code run when I work on the executive file without open (the access tables file) and without doing that from the executive file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible - the backend (data) file is "dead" in this regard.

The closest you can get some action in the backend, is to create [data macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-data-macros-to-a-table-event-f77ef125-7786-4c86-8933-7f284873dd8f?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: ok, thank you but how I can rename the tables according to the counter?

Comment: You can't, neither wouldn't you.  You will have to rethink this concept.